# C++: Convert unsigned long int into vector<uint8_t> raw data

Tags: c++, string, vector

I need to convert a `long int x = 0x9c758d0f` into a `vector<uint8_t> y = 9c 75 8d 0f`.

I was using:

```
std::stringsteam ss;
ss << std::hex << x;

std::string s = ss.str();

std::vector<uint8_t> y;
String2Vector(s,y);

    void String2Vector(std::string& in, std::vector<uint8_t>& output) 
    {
        std::vector<uint8_t> out;
        size_t len = in.length();

        for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i += 1) 
        {
            std::stringstream strm(in.substr(i, 1));
            uint8_t x;
            strm  >>std::hex>> x;
            out.push_back(x);
        }
        output = out;
    }
```

However, the `vector<uint8_t>` stored ASCII number instead of hex value.

What should I do in order to convert a `long int` into a raw data vector?
It's a multi-platform project so I don't wanna touch `memcpy()` etc.

---

**Update**: Pretty sure something went wrong:

```
long int x = 0x9c758d0f;
std::vector<uint8_t> v;
v.reserve(sizeof(x));
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x); ++i) {
    v.push_back(x & 0xFF);
    x = (x>>8);
}
PrintOutVector(v);

void PrintOutVector(std::vector<uint8_t>& in)
    {
        std::cout << "Vector Contains: ";
        for(std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator i=in.begin(); i != in.end(); ++i)
            std::cout << std::hex <<  *i ;
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
```

the output is ▒C▒▒h4

---

**Solution**: Much thanx to @WhozCraig @Anton Savin

```
long int x = 0x9c758d0f;
std::vector<uint8_t> v;
v.reserve(sizeof(x));
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x); ++i) {
    v.push_back(x & 0xFF);
    x = (x>>8);
}
PrintOutVector(v);

void PrintOutVector(std::vector<uint8_t>& in)
    {
        std::cout << "Vector Contains: ";
        for(std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator i=in.begin(); i != in.end(); ++i)
            std::cout << std::hex <<  static_cast<unsigned int>(*i)
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: If its multi-platform, hadn't you better also decide on a fixed with as well (something from `<cstdint>` such as `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`) ? And I assume you want network order (big-endian).

Comment: Try : `std::cout << std::hex <<  static_cast<unsigned int>(*i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which provides same results regardless of byte ordering:

```
long int x = 0x9c758d0f;
std::vector<uint8_t> v;
v.reserve(sizeof(x));
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x); ++i) {
    v.push_back(x & 0xFF);
    x >>= 8;
}
```

Comment: i understand n totally agree with this solution. But the output v contains ▒
(random unreadable value)

Comment: oh and im using debian, does it matter?

Comment: @YeWang no it shouldn't matter. What are you basing the claim "unreadable" from ? How are you concluding that? Properly done, the vector in the above will contain the octets `0x0f, 0x8d, 0x75, 0x9c`. That *order* may not be the one you want (you likely want big-endian), but the *content* should be correct.

Comment: @YeWang By adding an addendum section to the *end* of your question.

Comment: @YeWang I still strongly suggest you consider using a platform-independent type like your use of `uint8_t` and consider one of the 32-bit or 64-bit types (ex: `int64_t`) *and* encode and decode in a fixed consistent byte order (big-endian would be a good choice).

Answer (score 2):

```
long int x = 0x9c758d0f;
const uint8_t* begin = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&x);
const uint8_t* end = begin + sizeof(x);
std::vector<uint8_t> v(begin, end);
```

Note that the ordering depends on how your system arranges the bytes (big endian or little endian) in the `long`.  You can deal with this by first reordering the bytes to big-endian with a function like htonl(), except that is for `int` and there is no cross-platform one for `long` so you'll have to think about what to do there if you care about the byte ordering.

Comment: im dealing with a big-endian system. this code outputs a vector with some random value in it.  Trying change the bit order atm

Comment: If one needs a different endian representation, simply call `std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());`.

Answer (score 0):

Unions come in handy for this sort of stuff. Only issue is the byte ordering might vary based on endianness, which you have to account for.

```
union U{
    long int i;
    uint8_t uc[4];
};
U u = {0x9c758d0f};
std::vector<uint8_t> ucvec(u.uc, u.uc+4);
printf ("%x:%x:%x:%x\n", ucvec[3], ucvec[2], ucvec[1], ucvec[0]);
```

Comment: Since you are using C++, accessing the inactive member of a union is UB.

Comment: @T.C.: technically correct, but is there any implementation that wouldn't support this?

Comment: If you're going to do this (and I don't recommend it) at least use  `uint8_t uc[sizeof(i)];` for the array member. May as well account for *all* the octets.